How to check if a file uploaded to AWS S3 has the same content as a local file
We believe that the S3 checksum is useless for huge files larger than 1GB, as it is a further hashed value of chunks separated by an arbitrary number of bytes.
There is a 1 GB file uploaded to AWS S3.
The SHA256 checksum value is "o9mK1Ay32kIpvW157S40b/2siazR/+tpuz6OYCsjNBU=-2620".
Is there any way to verify that the file locally and the file uploaded to S3 are identical in content?
Without downloading of course.
I am hoping to use the AWS SDK or cli to calculate the same checksum value from the local file

Thats not a sha256, its an md5 + the number 2620. Generating crc/sha hashes are optional features selected at object/upload part creation. By default s3 uses the hash of hashes of each uploaded part for the object. If you take your file size and divide by 2620 that should give you roughly the size of those parts (i think chunks are to nearest megabit). From there you could generate and concatenate the hashes and hash them.  Or you could just download the file and compare locally :) - im going to vote to close as off-topic. You might try asking over on superuser.com instead. Good luck!

"as it is a further hashed value of chunks separated by an arbitrary number of bytes." do you have any reference to back up this claim?

I was able to get all hash values per chunk with the get-object-attributes command.
The byte counts are explicitly listed, so I assume they are complete.
[cloudshell-user ~]$ aws s3api get-object-attributes --bucket xxx --key "xxx.bin"    --object-attributes "Checksum,ObjectParts"
{
    "LastModified": "2024-07-10T20:56:50+00:00",
    "Checksum": {
        "ChecksumSHA256": "ZQHQKvGsIHCdKb9APtdkmY4RH/FwucuznEoShkrEPsw="
    },
    "ObjectParts": {
        "TotalPartsCount": 3106,
        "PartNumberMarker": 0,
        "NextPartNumberMarker": 1000,
        "MaxParts": 1000,
        "IsTruncated": true,
        "Parts": [
            {
                "PartNumber": 1,
                "Size": 5242880,
                "ChecksumSHA256": "nkyKW7CVp1UjpQX66AHwRp3tMTJmpguNoyz+S5lcwt8="
            },
略


From Checking object integrity - Amazon Simple Storage Service:

Amazon S3 uses checksum values to verify the integrity of data that you upload to or download from Amazon S3. In addition, you can request that another checksum value be calculated for any object that you store in Amazon S3. You can select from one of several checksum algorithms to use when uploading or copying your data. Amazon S3 uses this algorithm to compute an additional checksum value and store it as part of the object metadata.
When you upload an object, you can optionally include a precalculated checksum as part of your request. Amazon S3 compares the provided checksum to the checksum that it calculates by using your specified algorithm. If the two values don't match, Amazon S3 reports an error.

